# Docker volume container store in different drives

Tags: docker, containers, volume

I am looking at when i create a data volume container, can i specify where to store the data for this container? Example, i might want to have data volume container 1 sit at directory where my backend storage is SSD drive while data volume container 2 sit at directory where my backend storage is normal SATA drive. Thanks.

Cw

Answer (score 2):

First, you mount SSD drive to a folder. for example :

```
 mount /dev/ssd /datassd
```

Then, when you start a docker container 1, for example: you mount /datassd into /var/lib/mongodb for container 1.

```
docker run -d -v /datassd:/var/lib/mongodb .........
```

With other SATA drive, mount it into another folder

```
mount /dev/hhd /home/folderhhd
```

then start container 2:

```
docker run -v /home/folderhhd:/opt/app ...
```

Comment: note that to mount both you just need to add in another -v arg. `docker run -d -v /datassd:/var/lib/mongodb -v /home/folderhhd:/opt/app ...`

Comment: Can i achieve this without mounting host directory as data volume?

Comment: you mean, you have already had partitions for ssd and hhd drive ?

Comment: I understand what you try to say and i know how to implement what you proposed. what i mean is is there other way besides this, is this the only recommended way to do?

Comment: Do you guys have any experience on docker volume plugin?

Comment: I don't like this answer. The question asks about volumes, you're using bind mounts. They're different things.